# Performing Image Transformations Locally

Tags: image, image-transforms, permissions

Is there any reason why image transformations might not be working locally? I just get a bunch of these "http://site.dev/cpresources/transforms/7 404 (Not Found)" as error messages. The image directory has the correct permissions...﻿

Comment: Check your `craft\storage\runtime\logs` files for any relevant errors?

Comment: Same problem here on a local installation. Any ideas?

Comment: Are your Asset upload paths using environment-specific values?

Comment: @MichaelRog It's the default HappyLager site, so nothing environment-specific. Not a single transform works: all URLs are '/cpresources/transforms/' and I've verified that the 'assets' folder has permission of 777. Totally puzzled.

Answer (score 1):

It is very likely that your "File System Path" on the asset source is unsuitable for a local environment.

You can set the fileSystemPath in your config like this:

```
'environmentVariables' => array(
    'fileSystemPath' => '../../public'
)
```

Then you can change your asset source settings to something like the following:

[image: craftcms asset source settings]